# Limite máximo de caracteres de um endereço de e-mail

Tags: email

Quero validar um campo de e-mail tanto na página quanto no banco de dados, mas eu não sei qual é o limite de caracteres que um e-mail pode ter. Abraço!

Comment: {64}@{255}   isto é, 64 + 1 + 255 = 320

Answer (score 7):

A RFC 5321 especifica (seção 4.5.3): máximo de 256 caracteres para um e-mail completo.

Outros limites: 255 para o domínio, 64 para o nome de usuário (parte que vem antes do @).

Porém a recomendação é que os servidores aceitem endereços fora destes limites (4.5.3.1). São antes limites mínimos que o servidor deve implementar, não limites máximos para filtrar fora. (Mas realmente um e-mail mais comprido que 256 caracteres deve ser anômalo mesmo.)